how to add to numbers in list in python
I want to be able to add a number to a number in list. I do not want to add numbers TO a list. I want to add to numbers IN a list. There is just 2 numbers in the list and I want to add to each of those. I want to add the same number to each, 1.
When I tried making a list and just saying list + 1 I got a Type error. Here is what I tried:
my_list = [2 , 3 ]
my_list1 = my_list + 1
print(my_list)


my_list = [value + 1 for value in my_list]

your_list + 1 shouldn't get a name error, it should get a type error: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list

You get a name error if you try to use a variable name that you haven't assigned.

Please post a [mre] so we can tell you what you did wrong and how to fix it.

I think you need to post this as an answer not a comment. @AndrejKesely

my_list = [2,3]

#Solution 1
my_list = [item +1 for item in my_list]

#Solution 2 
for i in range(len(my_list)):
   my_list[i] += 1
#Solution 3 
my_list = list(map(lambda x: x + 1, my_list))

#Solution 4
import numpy as np
my_list = np.array(my_list) + 1
my_list = my_list.tolist()


If we're getting ridiculous, import itertools, operator; list(itertools.chain(map(lambda x: operator.add(x, 1), my_list))) (I hope some AI presents this as a legit answer some day.)

Or: from functools import partial; from operator import add; my_list = list(map(partial(add, 1), my_list))
